# Jekyll and Markdown are not generating pages

Tags: markdown, jekyll, liquid

I am new to Jekyll. I am developing a static website.  I am following the basic setup for a Blog, About, and Contact pages.  Below is my file structure.  I am using a Markdown approach for generating the Contact and About pages.  I execute this command to generate my site: `bundle exec jekyll serve`  From the file structure image you can see not about or contact directory is generate under the _site directory.

I have been trying to follow Josh Powell's [example](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/920#issuecomment-63093764).

Any suggestion are greatly appreciated.

Russ

This is the File from Visual Studio Code.
[image: File Structure]

This is the About.md page.

[image: About Page]

This is the Page layout template.

[image: Page Layout Template]

Comment: When I create 'about' and 'contact' directories in the project's root directory and run the jekyll  command, the pages generate with no problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like the previous answer mentions, directories starting with an underscore are given a special consideration in Jekyll.

To keep your root level tidy, just drop `about.md` and `contact.md` into a directory named simply **`pages`** (no leading underscore).
The permalink setting of `/about/` and `/contact/` for the two pages respectively will ensure that the pages are generated as desired.

Comment: Thank you.  I modified the directory structure as recommended by @marcanuy and yourself.  It worked has said.

Answer (score 0):

Directories starting with an underscore are special in Jekyll, put the about and contact page at root level without `_pages` and the will be generated in `_site`.

Comment: Thank you for responding.  I was hoping to keep my root level clean and tidy. :-)  I was able to make it work by manually creating directories under the root directory for the about and contact pages.  Next, I dropped in the *.md pages This was the only way I was able to make it work.  Is there a way by keeping the pages under the _pages directory?